# Loadrunner file upload

Tags: file-upload, loadrunner

I have Google'd this subject a lot over the past few days, but I cannot find a best practice solution. My question is basically how do I script in LR a fileupload? My app consists of a browse button, a pop up that lets me locate the file and it closes after I have located the file. Finally the app has a upload button to upload the file.
My script is recorded using URL mode and I guess I need to create some kind of custom request? URL mode creates somewhat complex scripts and placing custom requests inside these script is challenging.
BTW: I have not tried to record and play back the file upload process described yet, and using URL mode might just solve it without further customization? Or did someone actually made file upload using LR and URL mode work? A small example would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different applications will go about uploading a file from a client to a server in different ways. Your best bet is to record your application doing the upload and taking a look at what LoadRunner records.

Mark the point before and after the upload **as you record** by creating a transaction so you can easily find the spot in your code where the upload actually happens.